# Is it possibile to completely remove css .ng-invalid while keeping validators with MatFormFields?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-validation

I'm trying to have a login form with simple Validators.required fields, but I don't want to actually see the error color when .ng-invalid class applies to the input.
Is there an easy way to achieve this or do I really need to ovverride all css classes?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the class to render what you want